# POST /{application_id}, cannot update ios_bundle_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth, facebook-app-settings

Facebook's Graph API documentation lists the `application` object's `ios_bundle_id` field under the "[Updating](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application#Updating)" section. However, sending a `POST` request to update said field, e.g.

`POST: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{application_id}?ios_bundle_id=["com.Company.AppName"]&access_token={app_access_token}`

Responds with this error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) ios_bundle_id cannot be edited using the API. Please use the Developer App to edit settings instead.", 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "code": 100
    }
}
```

I am able to update this field through the Developer App page, but in my case, I need to update this field programmatically.

I have successfully tested that same `POST` request to update other fields, e.g. `app_name`, so I am certain the request is structured properly.

Has anyone encountered this issue, or similar? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The error message is very clear. It is not possible to do using the API

Comment: @WizKid, thank you for your response. The error message is indeed very clear, however it contradicts the Graph API documentation, see the page I've linked to above.

Comment: Then file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

This is a documentation error. This field is not editable via the Graph API. You have to go into your Facebook Application Dashboard and change it from there.

Here's a link to the bug report created to fix this:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1646835812217089/